# Define functions recursively with derivative in Python

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, sympy

How can I define a succession of functions h_k: k=1,2,3,...
by using two known functions f=f(x) and g=g(x) as follows:

h_1=f/g, 
h_{k+1}=diff(h_k,x)/g, for k=1,2,3,.....

Note that the new functions have two entries h(k,x)=h_k(x).
I want to do it in Sympy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `k` will always be an explicit integer, just use a Python function:

```
def h(x, k):
    if k == 1:
        return f(x)/g(x)
    return diff(h(x, k - 1), x)/g(x)
```

If you want to allow symbolic `k` (like `k = Symbol('k')`), subclass `sympy.Function`

```
class h(Function):
    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, x, k):
        if k.is_Integer and k.is_positive:
            if k == 1:
                return f(x)/g(x)
            else:
                return diff(h(x, k - 1), x)/g(x)
```

(note that if `eval` returns `None` (i.e., it hits the bottom of the function without returning), the function will remain unevaluated.

Note that we check `k.is_Integer` with a capital `I` (*not* `k.is_integer`). This means that `k` is an explicit integer, like 1, 2, 3, .... `k.is_integer` would also be true for `Symbol('k', integer=True)`, but we don't want to evaluate in this case because we don't know which integer it is.